# Convert IEnumerable<JToken> to IEnumerable<String>

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this sample Json:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> a = JArray.Parse("[{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}]");
```

I want to convert it to `IEnumerable<String>` by concatenating all the values. I tried following LINQ query, it performs concatenation correctly but it returns back `IEnumerable<JToken>`

```
var t = a.Select(x => x.Values().Aggregate((i, j) => $"{i}|{j}")).ToList();
```

How do I convert to `IEnumerable<String>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you select the token's `Value<string>` method (which converts it to a `string`), it should give you what you're looking for:

```
List<string> result = a
    .Select(token => token.Values().Aggregate((i, j) => $"{i}|{j}").Value<string>())
    .ToList();
```